# when I viewing the schedule in CF admin it throws an error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

If I view the schedule tasks in CF-Administrator it throws the error
**The system has attempted to use an undefined value, which usually indicates a programming error, either in your code or some system code.
Null Pointers are another name for undefined values.** 
Please share the thoughts about how to solve it?

Comment: Do you mean when you click on specific schedule task or you are not able to get into schedule task manager? Also what version you are using?

Comment: What happens when you run the page the implements the scheduled task?